# Chemistry — Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

**We want to congratulate and thank everyone that helped this site and community grow healthily into what they are today!**

If you can find your name among the top 72 users in the first two pages [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all), we have a surprise for you!

[image: The element of surprise!]
<sub><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub>Hoping to get a reaction with that joke... (｡ˇ艸ˇ)</sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sub>

We want to send you a token of our appreciation for being among the most prolific users in this community! As such, we're sending you a little box, inside which you'll find:

**A T-SHIRT!**

[image: T-SHIRTS!!!!!!!]

**STICKERS!**

[image: STICKERS!!!!!!!]

**A BEAKER-STYLE MUG!**

[image: MUG!!!!!!!!!!]

I'll be reaching out to you later today with a link to a form: be sure to fill out the form as soon as you're able to do so! You'll have two weeks to do it, after which I'll close the form and take care of sending all of the swag your way! It should take from 6 to 8 weeks for the package to be delivered to you!

If you're not on the list, don't worry too much about it — we've got some extra swag stored we can send to you for events and such!

**Thanks to all of you for making this site great!**

Comment: :O $%I just peed in my pants$

Comment: I took the liberty to once again thank our great users for being the awesome people they are. Special thanks to people who lent me a hand in TRE 1! Never cease to be cool, @Community

Comment: wow just got E-mail! :D

Comment: Awesome news! Does the t-shirt (or the sticker) have the URL on it? I'd love to publicize some (e.g., at conferences).

Comment: @GeoffHutchison It does not, no.

Comment: Woooooooo! Also, that beaker is awesome!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks to all!

Comment: Oh wow. I don't even feel I'm worthy for this - I guess this means that I will have to answer some more questions now!

Comment: This site helped me get my BA and it turns around and decides to give a thank you gift for using it. I'm humbled. Thanks to everyone who has made this site what it is: users, mods, and devs. Please keep up the amazing work.

Comment: This is a very nice thing that you are doing. I agree with Geoff - I would love for this swag to have urls or site names. Regardless, if I have my t-shirt in time for the ACS meeting in March, expect me to be wearing it one day.

Comment: Sigh!!! Not in the top-72 ;/

Comment: Here's a reaction for you: $\ce{Nicolau + TUS -> Nicolau}^{*}$, where the asterisk indicates a long-lived excited state!

Comment: Well, that email brought me back, so I guess I'll have to answer some meatier questions, rather than the fluff I poke at when I'm tired. O_O

Comment: Barely made it. I am on the third page.

Comment: @Simon-Nail-It: Me too ;(

Comment: What about us biology folks :P

Comment: Biology is one of the next in line, @WYSIWYG ;)

Comment: This is great! Has anyone received their swag package yet?

Comment: Impossible, @Dissenter: it hasn't been shipped yet ;)

Comment: The swag has been shipped out last week! Enjoy it!

Answer (score 39):

## Swagtacular thanks to the Stack Exchange team!

Being one of the proud users on the list I can only saw I was very pleasantly surprised when I saw the e-mail arriving. It’s great of you to honour contributors in the way you decided to do.

But seriously, thanking us users is not enough. We have to thank the awesome people that make this thing possible, too! No, I’m not talking about our bosses/families/friends who have to endure many a user spending too much time on Stack Exchange. I want to thank **you!**

Thank you, dear Stack Exchange team, for building a great site, for allowing us to participate here for free, for caring for the community and for keeping it together with events such as this one or Winterbash! Without you, we all wouldn’t be here (but we would have had much more free time on our hands ;)).

Comment: *but we would have had much more free time on our hands* Um, indeed.

Comment: Thank you for being an awesome community!

Answer (score 27):

[image]

Comment: Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.

Answer (score 22):

[image]

Answer (score 20):

Just got my package yesterday and I've already got colleagues asking about it, so maybe we'll have some new users soon. Thanks to everyone for making the site as great as it is!

[image: my swag]
(the t-shirt's in the wash)

Comment: mine is on the way!

Answer (score 20):

Just in time for the lab photo! Thanks for the goodies, JNat!

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Got mine a while ago. Here are some pictures:

Pen holder:

[image]

Sticker on my office door:

[image]

T-shirt after washing:

[image]