# T-shirt for sale?

Tags: discussion

Is there any place I could order one of these?

[image]

So I guess there is an idea to embroider (made with tools from https://www.vistaprint.com):

[image]

Detail:

[image]

I wonder if benzene is under copyright.

Comment: There was a time where Stack Exchange sent out such items to the top users: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3132/4945 I'd assume there's a question regarding this on mother meta, but since I've not yet heard about shop.stackexchange.com, my answer to your question is leaning towards no.

Comment: Maybe I could make my own.

Comment: Maybe I could make them for the outgoing moderators?

Comment: That would require you to know rather more information about me than I’d like :p

Comment: I know, maybe a dead drop in Oxford. Or give it to Jan, who gives it to Martin, who gives it to you. Or just give away the design, and everyone prints their own. @orthocresol

Comment: This is of course a matter of taste, but I personally think it would look much cooler in black, with that design as a small logo at the upper left, rather than having the large billboard-sized design.  Or maybe even a black shirt with that as a raised embroidered black design. But, certainly, à chacun son goût.

Comment: I like the idea. As someone whose personal information is a Google-click away, put me down for a medium :)